# React hooks only setting the initial state

Tags: reactjs, setstate

React noob here.
I'm trying to set the state on the onChange trigger.
But it's not taking the textbox value and setting it.
It continues to keep the initial value.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import {  Button, Form, Checkbox, TextField, FormLayout, Select, Spinner, Toast, Banner } from "@shopify/polaris";

function CourierSettings() {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const toggleLoading = useCallback(() => setIsLoading((isLoading) => !isLoading), []);

    const handleSubmit = useCallback((_event) => { }, []);

    const spinnerMK = isLoading ? (
        <Spinner accessibilityLabel="Updating" size="small"/>
    ) : 'Save';

    const [clientId, setClientId] = useState('test');
    const [clientIdError, setClientIdError] = useState('');
    const handleClientIdChange = useCallback((newValue) => {
        console.log(newValue); setClientId(newValue); console.log(clientId)
    }, []);

    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FormLayout>
                
                <TextField
                    requiredIndicator={true}
                    label="Client ID"
                    value={clientId}
                    onChange={handleClientIdChange}
                    autoComplete="off"
                    error={clientIdError}
                />
                <Button submit>{spinnerMK}</Button>
            </FormLayout>
        </Form>
    );
}

export default CourierSettings;
```

In the code above, when I console log the clientId value, it only displays the initial value.

I've also tried using `onChange={setClientId}` but haven't worked either.

No errors in the console either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The call to `useCallback` also needs dependencies.  Namely, `setClientId` and `clientId`.  (Though the latter can be eliminated once you remove the second `console.log` statement.)

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Happy to mark it as the answer if you want it put it.